# Character limit in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, my vs code will only take 100 characters on one line.

Can someone tell me how do I change these settings.

I tried File-->Preferences-->Settings but I cannot find the right option.

Comment: word wrap  column

Comment: Widen the window. Forced wrapping is not turned on by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can set number of characters in one line in VS Code:

1. Open Settings in VS Code and search for "word wrap". Select "wordWrapColumn" in Word Wrap dropdown.
2. If you scroll down, you will find "Word Wrap Column" with input field. There you can define number of characters like "100".